# ProjectEuler2-(my own solution)

Tags: c

I have tried to solve Project Euler problem 2 by a for loop. I'm new to c programming and I cannot seem to get the algorithm right. 
3524579

The for loop is suppose to look at for the 32 fibonacci which is less than 4000000. Then I have defined the fibonacci function and after than I want to add the even fibonacci numbers by the second for loop.

I get 3524579, can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

/* Edited:
     Ok, I rewrote the code using your tips. I do not understand why this does  not       work. I tried to write each steps down on paper:
    The predicate is evaluated b mod 2 == 0, so the following happends:

sum = 2 + 0

a = b   -> a == 2

b = sum -> b == 2
    These steps iterate until the value 4mill. Can someone see what I fail to not see :p?*/

**New edited version: I finally it work using a for-loop. Just wondering if there was a prettier way to do it using for-loop maybe.**

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int result = 0;
    int sum = 0;





    for(;;){

        if(!(b < 4000000)) break;
        if(b % 2 == 0)
        result = result + b;


        sum = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = sum;
        printf("%d\n", result);


    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

1. Notice that your answer is equal to the 31st fib number + 1. This means you are replacing your total with new values on every iteration instead of keeping a running total.
2. Consider looping until the current fib number gets > 4M instead of figuring out beforehand that there are 32 fib numbers you need to look at.

Comment: Thanks alot, I did not realize I was replacing the total each time.

Comment: Hi again ben4808, I would appreciate if you could review the updated question :p.

Comment: I won't just give you the answer, but if you're still stuck, think about how you would do this by hand. Then mentally step through your code line by line and make sure the right things are happening at each step. If you have a debugger to run your code in, even better.

Comment: No, I did not ask for the answer :). I was just pondering if I was slightly closer or circling forever around it the wrong way. It's fine, I will keep trying and figure it out eventually, just very tedious for a guy with my programming skills. Right now I get 1255175738